# Регулярные выражения. Флаг /u. Unicode

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
/hell\u{6F}/u.test('hello'); // -> true
/hell\u{6F}/.test('hello'); // -> false
```

Объясните специфику работы флага `/u` в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто как топор:

С этим флагом регулярка понимает выражения типа `\u{6f}` внутри регулярки, как юникод символ, без него - понимает как строку из последовательных символов u,{,6,f,}

Главная специфика тут одна: это фича появившаяся в ecmascript-6 стандарте, то есть без предварительной компиляции в ecmascript-5 код ее [**поймут не все браузеры.**](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags)

Есть еще один небольшой нюанс:
Пусть x - это не эскейп символ, тогда это синтаксически валидная регулярка:

```
var c = /\x/
```

А это - нет:

```
var c = /\x/u
```